# in Dropdown multilevel menu, submenu is not stable it is disappear when iam hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here am posting the html code. My doubt is I have one menu under sub menu. If you see example here : Products => under this 3 submenus i.e item1,item2,item3. If you move over on item3 again i need to display submenus related to the item3 menu. Please check below screenshot also . where can i wrong in my code. Can any one please tell me .[Click here and see if user mouse over on item-3 after displaying item-31,item-32,item-33. Am trying to select item-31 not showing suddenly closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc20T.png)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>dropdown</title>
    <style>
    #nav-main li a.nav-link {
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        padding-top: 28px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }

    #nav-main a.nav-link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #8c8c8c;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .sub-menu-panel {
        display: none;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-top: 3px solid #212121;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
        margin-top: -3px;
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }
    ul li.sub-menu:hover div.sub-menu-pannel{display:grid;}
    ul.nav > li.dropdown:hover > div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;}
    li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;position: absolute;left: -159px;top: 53px;}
    li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown + div.dropdown-menu > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;}
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
     <nav role="navigation" id="nav-main" class="okayNav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Employee Login</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown sub-menu active">
                    <a alt="Sencillo" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-hover="dropdown">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-panel">
                      <a href="#">item-1</a>
                      <a href="#">item-2</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-3</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#">item-31</a>
                        <a href="#">item-32</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-33</a>
                          <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="#">item-33-1</a>
                            <a href="#">item-33-2</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#leave-message">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->



    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>dropdown</title>
    <style>
    #nav-main li a.nav-link {
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        padding-top: 28px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }

    #nav-main a.nav-link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #8c8c8c;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .sub-menu-panel {
        display: none;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-top: 3px solid #212121;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
        margin-top: -3px;
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }
    ul li.sub-menu:hover div.sub-menu-pannel{display:grid;}
    ul.nav > li.dropdown:hover > div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;}
    li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;position: absolute;left: -159px;top: 53px;}
    li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown + div.dropdown-menu > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;}
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
     <nav role="navigation" id="nav-main" class="okayNav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Employee Login</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown sub-menu active">
                    <a alt="Sencillo" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-hover="dropdown">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-panel">
                      <a href="#">item-1</a>
                      <a href="#">item-2</a>
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-3</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#">item-31</a>
                        <a href="#">item-32</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-33</a>
                          <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="#">item-33-1</a>
                            <a href="#">item-33-2</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#leave-message">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>




  <li class="dropdown sub-menu active">
                <a alt="Sencillo" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-hover="dropdown">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-panel">
                  <a href="#">item-1</a>
                  <a href="#">item-2</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-3</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a href="#">item-31</a>
                    <a href="#">item-32</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-33</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#">item-33-1</a>
                        <a href="#">item-33-2</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </li>
```

li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;position: absolute;left: -185px;top: 124px;}
li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown + div.dropdown-menu > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In multilvel dropdown ..when iam hover dropdown it is showing but when i was moving to next submenu it is not stable it was disappears

Comment: Then you need to [edit] this **and the proper code** into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the StackOverflow guide for future questions. More complex problems will be impossible to solve without proper formatting.

That being said, your problem is the `a:hover`, you have to do the hover on `<li>`, so change
`li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu` to `li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel:hover > div.dropdown-menu`.

The reason is, that when you move to the submenu, you are not hovering the `<a>` anymore, so `a:hover` is not true anymore. But the submenu is inside the `<li>`, so you will still be hovering the `<li>` and the submenu won't disappear

Comment: actually i had tried this li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel:hover > div.dropdown-menu, when iam using > symbol sub menu is not showing , when iam using + symbol submenu is showing but when iam hover the submenu is disapperaing li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel:hover > div.dropdown-men